# Silverlight media element not showing buffering state after increase play rate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, silverlight

I am using silverlight plugin for playing media files.

I am taking Play rate control for increase/decrease media play rate speed.

There is on pop up with progress bar which is shown when media element is in buffering mode.

This is code for checking media is buffering mode.

```
if(_myMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Buffering)
{
  //Show pop_up for with buffering progress bar
}
```

Issue : when I increase play rate using play rate slider control and than **increase media position by reset media element with new time span position** than media element goes buffering mode. but _myMediaElement.CurrentState is always showing playing mode. therefore unable to showing pop_up for with buffering progress bar.

Code for changing play rate

```
_myMediaElement.PlaybackRate = _playRateSliderControl.Value; // it can be 0.5, 1.0, 1.5
```

Code for increase media position

```
_myMediaElement.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, newPosition);
```

Any help is appreciate

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it. 
when I increase playrate from 1.0 than if media element is in buffering process that time I have assign 
playrate = 1.0 and take in another variable of increase playrate value. and than when buffering is completed and media element player played the stream than reset playrate by increase value.